# Links in reviews, good or bad?

Tags: discussion, support, review

[image]

First of all, Its is a good feature : fake posts to check whether the reviewer is paying attention or not.

But It seems to have a little problem. One could **easily** find out that its a test like : ( **sometimes antecedently** )

- Clicking on **`share`** to see the full post but finding out that the **post does not exists**
- No username : "Askubuntu user" in username field
- When tried to edit.

I dont know a good solution for this to make a **suggestion**, but you can try  :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main point of the audits is that you are paying attention and not robo-reviewing. If you did spot any of these, you are paying attention. As Randall Munroe would say (see last pane):

[image: And what about all the people who won't be able to join the community because they're terrible at making helpful and constructive co-- ... oh.]

Comment: Pretty much. That's how this works!