# Bug in the audit system?

Tags: discussion, bug, editing, review-audits

I believe I've discovered a bug in the audit system.

I was reviewing this answer, which obviously needed some serious work:
[image]

---

So I clicked on the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/772307/edit) link, and it showed me this:

[image]

---

## Which immediately told me that it was an audit.

I flagged as low quality, and sure enough, it was an audit.

Comment: I'd call this a pass. You were paying attention ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Links in reviews, good or bad?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15089/links-in-reviews-good-or-bad)

Comment: @muru I don't think this is a duplicate, but it is related. I would still assume that this a bug, and maybe tell the user that they passed/failed the audit when edit button is clicked, instead of going to a [blank page](http://askubuntu.com/posts/772307/edit).

Comment: @Dan something wrong with the link? It didn't lead me to a blank page

Comment: @muru Maybe because you are >20k rep. But for me it shows a blank page with a message saying "This post is deleted and cannot be edited.", same as the screenshot shown by the OP. No links, no branding, etc.

Comment: @Dan that could be worth a bug. In this case, though, I think just clicking on the edit button doesn't open this page - you have to open it in a new tab for that to happen. Like the links in the other question.

Comment: @muru Since you showed up here, do you think you coould shed some light on this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/774162/change-mac-permanentlyfor-wlan0/774176?noredirect=1#comment1159298_774176