# White page (no HTML) when trying to edit a question

Tags: bug

I think I've found a possible bug on AskUbuntu. Earlier, I was trying to edit [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811402/proxy-authentication-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-chrome).

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

As you can see, the webpage looks fine and normal. But when I click on the `edit` link to edit it, I immediately get the message: `"There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes."`

All it would be also fine and normal, but...

[image: message on blank page]

...the above mentioned message shows up on a completely blank page. No HTML, no website. I had to hit the `back` button in the browser in order to get back to "reality".

I'm a bit puzzled. I don't even know what to ask. I guess that there is a slight technical problem with AskUbuntu website and I feel the need to report it. This problem may occur to other users too.

Comment: Yeah... one of these days we need to rewrite the edit pipeline to show stuff like this as regular errors rather than what happens now. It is, unfortunately, a fairly complex change. I'm adding a Trello card about this to our tech debt backlog.

Comment: I had a similar experience: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15442/bug-in-the-audit-system

Answer (score 3):

This problem is a very rare case, which probably won't be addressed anytime soon as it would probably prove to be complicated.
Normally, when you open a post that still has a pending suggested edit, the edit/improve this question button is completely removed.

Although, instead of having a fix for this issue, a feature request to show a more "beautiful" layout for errors may prove to be more friendly. As these errors seem to have this blank page as the current default layout.
Another similar example: [Bug in the audit system?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15442/bug-in-the-audit-system)

---

Basically what happened in your case is the following:

- You and someone else opened the Question's page
- Both of you saw an issue with the post, so you wanted to improve it by editing it.
- That other person was slightly faster and had already submitted a pending edit suggestion.
- While you still have that page opened, and you still haven't refreshed, you clicked on the edit link.
- Since the Stack Exchange engine does not allow more than one suggested edit at the same time, you got the following error:

  > There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.

<sup>This is not a solution for your issue, nor a fix. It's just an explanation of the bug that happened</sup>